# adb gps location command can't change location using current version of emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, gps, adb, appium

- device: emulator nexus 6
- os: android 8

   
  When I try to change GPS-coordinates using command  `adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 emu geo fix 24.00112 49.80276` (from appium log) coordinates were changed.
  But after some time (about 1 second) coordinates were returned to coordinates provided on "emulator Extended controls" page from emulator setting menu:

   
  [image: emulator Extended controls - GPS TAB]
  How make my GPS (setted by adb command) stay on emulator without changes?
  **PS: current issue appears after the last update of Android SDK and tools**
   
  [image: about emulator version]

**FIXED**
 You can load temporary build using [this temporary link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1p4q_CDvpkIzLjRRDUFZHV0sz5rAuIUdK) 
fixed version will be enabled soon in regular Android SDK updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I report the  [BUG](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73471760) to official Android Studio support.
They solved that issue.
Will wait until updated emulator will be available.
You can get fixed emulators from [this temporary link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1p4q_CDvpkIzLjRRDUFZHV0sz5rAuIUdK)

**Update:** Emulator 27.1.11 canary with the fix is live now.